# como usar el id que llega del boton hacia la funcion dentro de mi codigo

Tags: javascript

mi duda es como usar la variable numero del boton hacia la funcion
le coloco let itemProducto = Productos.find(a=>a.id==id)
o
let itemProducto = Productos.id;
luego en el if coloco && itemProducto ==true
pero no muestra como repetidos, salvo , creo que el primero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**solo me preciona el primer elemento **

```
    <tbody  id="productos_content">
    
        @foreach($Variables as $e)
        <tr>
     <td>
           <?php
         printf('<button id= class="button" onclick="addToCarritoItem(' . $e->id_productos . 
         ')">Añadir</button>');
        ?>
     </td>
     </tr>
       
    @endforeach
    
    </tbody>

const Clickbutton = document.querySelectorAll('.button')

 Clickbutton.forEach(btn => {
      btn.addEventListener('click', addToCarritoItem)
   })

   function addToCarritoItem(id){
let item = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
 if(item) {console.log("Repetido");
 }else console.log("NO Repetido");

 var id_ncap= document.querySelector('.id_n').textContent
 var idcap= document.querySelector('.id_prod').textContent
 var codigocap= document.querySelector('.codigo').textContent   
     let Productos = {
     id_n: id_ncap,
     id: idcap,
      codigo: codigocap
};

 let itemProducto = Productos;
 let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
   if(itemCarrito){
 //console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemCarrito.cantidad){
  return;
}
  itemCarrito.cantidad++;
  document.getElementById("PRE_" +id).value=itemCarrito.cantidad;
 }
```

else{
itemCarrito = structuredClone(itemProducto); //creamos un clon para agregarlo al carrito
itemCarrito.cantidad=1;
itemCarrito.precio=0;
carrito.push(itemCarrito);

```
//renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
carrito_content.innerHTML+= interpolate(templateRowCarrito.innerHTML,itemCarrito);
```

}

//updatecantidad(id,itemCarrito.cantidad);
}

```js
const Clickbutton = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

 


const cuandoSeHaceClick = function (evento) {

    console.log("El texto que tiene es: ", this.innerText);
this.innerText;

    this.style.borderColor = "blue";
}

Clickbutton.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', cuandoSeHaceClick);
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  </head>
  <body>
        <button class="button">Añadir</button>
    <button class="button">Añadir</button>
    <button class="button">Añadir</button>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que faltaría es que primero, seleccione todos los botones para un estilo reset o como estaba. Luego dar estilo solamente al que se ha seleccionado con `evento.target`

```js
const Clickbutton = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

const cuandoSeHaceClick = function (evento) {

    console.log("El texto que tiene es: ", this.innerText);

    this.innerText;
    
    Clickbutton.forEach(e => e.style.borderColor = "");
    
    evento.target.style.borderColor = "blue";
};

Clickbutton.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', cuandoSeHaceClick);
});
```

```html
<button class="button">Uno</button>
<button class="button">Dos</button>
<button class="button">Tres</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Delega el evento](https://osmancea.medium.com/delegaci%C3%B3n-de-eventos-del-dom-con-javascript-d28131d43686) `click` al documento (o bien al contenedor en donde se encuentran los botones) y, a partir de la clase asignada a estos, identifica si el elemento *clickeado* (al cual puedes acceder por medio de la propiedad `target`) es uno de dichos botones. Una vez logrado esto, puedes proceder a realizar las acciones pertinentes a partir de los datos relacionados con el botón afectado.

Sería algo como esto:

```javascript
document.addEventListener("click", evento => {
    const elementoClickeado = evento.target;

    if (elementoClickeado.classList.contains("nombre de la clase de los botones")){
        /**
          * Aquí puedes acceder a las propiedades del botón:
          * 
          * elementoClickeado.id: El valor del ID del botón
          * elementoClickeado.innerText: El texto del botón
          * ...
          */
    }
}, false);
```

Un saludo